# Gulp — how to get lazy, ‘make’-like building?

Tags: css, node.js, makefile, gulp, less

I am using [gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) for css and js processing. Sometimes I am missing the good old lazyness of the unix [make](https://www.cs.swarthmore.edu/~newhall/unixhelp/howto_makefiles.html) command:

- only generate transformed (whatsover, e.g. compilation) files from original files, that have actually changed (based on time stamps).
- this is true from stage 1 to 2 (.cpp -> .o), stage 2 to 3 (linking or other stuff) whatever your dependency graph gives...

Make is not limited to source code: You can do image manipulation in several steps (efficiently ‘lazy’ generation of downscaled thumbs for example) or much else. All based on the fairly simple rule: *„is at least one of the source files newer in respect to the current output file(s)?“*

Unlike gulp, every step generates (more or less temporary) files, not a continuous pipe.

### Is there a way, to get the same kind of lazyness in gulp**, i.e. when generating css?

- only transform those (less|sass|stylus) files➝css if something changed (on the very respective file)
- same for adding in browser prefixes, concat, minify

Admittedly, beyond the first 1 or 2 steps, the output is most likely already a single stream. So any change means ‘touched’. Still, when playing for example with minify options, I'd rather be lazy about the early transpile, prefixing and concat stages (drawing prior results from a temp file). Also on the javascript side ( typeScript, ... )

[lazypipe](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lazypipe) and [gulp-cache](https://github.com/jgable/gulp-cache) sound tempting but are something else, if I understand correctly. Saying [.watch()](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-watch) is also only a partial answer, for the very first stage.

**Is there a more generic approach?**

Answer (score -1):

If you're set on using Gulp, then [this](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/incremental-builds-with-concatenate.md) would seem to be the way to do it. It involves the *gulp-cached* and *gulp-remember* plugins.